# Why does "addres(this)" output the name of the contract before the address in my dapptools test? Is there a way to return only the address?

Tags: solidity, addresses, dapptools

Any time I log an address using:

`emit log_address(address(_contract));`

the output always looks like:

`ContractName@0x...contract address...`

I am running rests with dappTools to show this.

Using dappTools logs to show the result of the tests.

Comment: Why are you still using dapptools? [The torch has been passed to Foundry](https://twitter.com/gakonst/status/1506669474920886273).

Comment: Because I missed that tweet... ok thanks for the info!  Switching now...